# TypeScript 3.8.3 not narrowing union type in switch statement

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript3.8

Here's a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.8.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgGwM7IDeAUMmcgnGAFxEC+p5AJgPYDmthDDMAriAjDAWIZACMoLANYQQAZQDuwMAgAWAHgAqyCAA9IIJgRkBPFjDQZs+AHwAKOFdy1NASiKMyeJStXIHTjjuJOShFHB4KABElGBR1J5hoQD0ycjABLGJSWQSEHBS2eSUkchRrGzxRUmp6QQV1WF5BY1MEPC8ODSNoQgieGDIUBDYoKBs6FjOyCAQAG7QyAC8yI5TOIncxMR8AkIiyAosUFLjispqAeu0MVRRyAA+ZRVRwYneF35X1m854aW3OIJP4pNIZcJgHrkZqFP4laIvYEgsi1cENZG5YYtP5tDpdJHIvogAZDEZwMYgCaBWizBZQZarQKbYh0IA).

```
interface Animals {
    cat: {}
    dog: {}
}
function brokenSwitch<T extends keyof Animals>(animal: T) {
    switch (animal) {
        case "cat":
            break
        case "dog":
            break
        default:
            // the line below has a TS error.
            // Type "cat" | "dog" is not assignable to type "never".
            const remainingAnimal: never = animal
    }
}
```

In the above code, I would expect the type of `animal` in the `default` case to be `never`, but it is not.

In my real use case, I need the function to accept a generic similar to this function. How can I get TS to narrow down the type of `animal` successfully as we go through the switch block?

I notice that from TS 4.3.5 and on, the type is narrowed the way I'd expect (the error disappears), but I can't change the TS version of my project.

Comment: Well, if you really can't update your TS version (which seems untenable in the long run) you can pretty much only widen your generic to a specific and narrow that like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mL22vw).  Does that meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That's a decent workaround, thank you for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

Before TypeScript 4.3, the way to deal with your problem would be to widen `animal` from the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `T` to the specific type `keyof Animals` to which it is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints).  This is most easily done by assigning `animal` to a new variable which is [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) as the specific type.  Such an assignment is seen as safe by the compiler.  Afterward, you use the new variable which will then be [narrowed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) as expected:

```
function repairedSwitch<T extends keyof Animals>(animal: T) {
    const _animal: keyof Animals = animal // widen
    switch (_animal) {
        case "cat":
            // is cat
            break
        case "dog":
            // is dog
            break
        default:
            const remainingAnimal: never = _animal // okay
    }
}
```

So that works, and the end of the answer to the question as asked.

---

Obligatory disclaimer:

Note that the "correct" answer is to upgrade to the latest TypeScript release, both to take advantage of [the support for contextual narrowing of generic values added in TypeScript 4.3](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-3.html#contextual-narrowing-for-generics) and to avoid the rapidly increasing amount of [technical debt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt) that comes from a depending on a static version of a language under such active development.  Bug fixes are rarely backported to previous versions (see [microsoft/TypeScript#38237](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38237)), so it's not really possible to subscribe to a "long-term support" version of TypeScript 3.8, which eventually becomes bug-free and is accompanied by  a large amount of accurate documentation and other development resources.

You (the OP of this question) may have valid reasons for sticking with a static version of the language, but you (other people who read this answer in the future) should strongly consider upgrading if at all possible.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.8.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgGwM7IDeAUMmcgnGAFxEC+p5AJgPYDmthDDMAriAjDAWIZFAgAHOMHFMAygHdgYBAAsAPABVkEAB6QQTAgGsIATxYw0GbPgB8ACjg3ctTQEoijMghF4wyAD6zliuyKYWVuih+MgAvMghtt7IeEoqqsgOwS44niTkhRRweCgARJRgZdQpReQA9PXIwASVtXXIAEbicMbtPiXlrGzV-UWNzQTDY4XdEL1jTBDwvDg0M+S+IP5iENigoGzRtrQgEABu0PFBSbgp3MTEQA)